# Combobox ON_CHANGING Event fired once

Tags: combobox, zk

I have a autodrop Combobox and a EventListener for the "Events.ON_CHANGING". My problem is that only work once.

Example, I type,do the search, I erase the values, retype and no event is fired. I need to click in other component and then re-click on the combobox to type another time.

My code:

```
public class ComboUsuariosComponent extends Combobox {

    public ComboUsuariosComponent(String width, boolean buttonVisible, boolean autodrop) {
        this.setButtonVisible(buttonVisible);
        this.setAutodrop(autodrop);
        this.setWidth(width);
        this.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHANGING, new GrillaComboOnChange());
    }

    private class GrillaComboOnChange implements EventListener<Event>{

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            finUsers(getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i miss this.setInstant(true);